# what's the meaning of this[i] in c++ without overloading

Tags: c++

This is the code from WebKit:

```
class ExecState : public Register 
{
 JSValue calleeAsValue() const { return this[JSStack::Callee].jsValue(); } 
 ... 
}
```

`JSStack::Callee` is `const`, `Operator[]` is not overloading in `ExecState` or `Register`,

So what's the syntax in c++ of `this[JSStack::Callee]` ?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the code and seeing what happens?

Comment: Uhh that's not a good thing. If `JSStack::Callee` does not evaluate to 0, you've got big problems. If it does, you've really still got problems.

Comment: Don't try this at home?

Comment: I guess it could work if you know that `*this` is an element of an array of the same type (and not a subtype!). But it's an ugly hack.

Comment: It calls `operator[]` of the current class (or one that it is derived from, if not defined in the current class), with `this` as the hidden this-pointer argument, and `JSStack::Callee` as the argument.

Comment: @MatsPetersson No, `this` is a pointer type.  The behavior you describe would be achieved by `(*this)[/*...*/]`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: applying the subscript operator to a pointer *never* calls a user-defined function! The subscript operator has to be a member, i.e., it `JSStack::Callee` can't help.

Comment: Doh! Yes, of course. So we have to assume that `this` is a member of a `ExecState` array (or something else with contiguous memory allocation)

Comment: @ interjay, @ Mats Petersson, I guess this is a member too, not sure.But if 'this' is not the start of a array(like this = &exec_array[2]),'this[JSStack::Callee]' will point to other place. That will be a bad design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `this` is a pointer to an `ExecState` and using the subscript operator with a pointer makes it behave as if it is an array. That is, the expression `this[JSStack::Callee]` accesses an object which is `JSStack::Callee` elements away from `this`. Of course, this can only possibly work if the element is a member of an array of `ExecState` objects.

Below is a quick stand-alone demo of using this "feature". In general I'd recommend against using it but there may be very specific needs where it is known that a type is used within an array and the accesses are viable. For example, if the type is defined locally, all known uses could be known (I'd add a comment stating that assumption, though).

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
    int d_value;
public:
    foo(int i): d_value(i) {}
    int get(int i) const { return this[i].d_value; }
};

template <typename T, int Size>
int size(T(&)[Size]) { return Size; }

int main()
{
    foo f[] = { 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5 };
    for (int i=0; i < size(f) - 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << "f[" << i << "].get(2)=" << f[i].get(2) << '\n';
    }
}
```